# How do I assert that a character belongs to a list of expected values?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert

I have a test method:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void test_chars()
    {
        MyBO target = new MyBO() { x = 'S' };
        char[] expected = {'D','d','M','m','L','l'};
        char actual = target.x;
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected); // ?
    }
```

How can i check with `Assert.AreEqual` if `target.x` is in that `char[] expected`? So if `'S'` isn't part of that array, the test should fail. Is this possible?

Comment: in a land far far away, there was an arcane programming dialect, and it was named 'c#'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Assert.IsTrue( ((IList)expected).Contains(actual));
```

Comment: Array.Contains does not exist. What do u mean?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Wrote before I checked the syntax.  It's fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I like the following:

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.Any(x => x == actual));
```

This can be customized based on whatever type of comparison you need.

Comment: Assert.IsTrue(expected.Any(x => x == actual));
  does not work.. there is no 'Any' method for expected, which is a char[] .

Comment: What release of .Net are you using?  This should work in .Net 3.5 and newer.  This is an extension method on Array.

Comment: Make sure you have using System.Linq; at the top of your code file.